# Configuring a cisco switch to work with a single ISP

Tags: networking, cisco, router, switch

I have a 6500 connected to my ISP and to a server. I have a /24 from my ISP and a /30. I have a default route set 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 isp gateway and have assigned one ip from the /30 to the interface connected to my ISP and am able to ping google.com etc. from the 6500. I have my server on a vlan and the server is configured to the 2nd IP in the /24 block I am just addressing the whole block at this time so the server's netmask is just 255.255.255.0 and the gateway is the first ip in the /24 block (the ip of the vlan). I am able to ping the 6500 from the server but am unable to ping external addresses.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the routing working so that I can ping external addresses?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to put the /24 block on the other side of a router (which is essentially what a layer 3 switch like this is) your ISP needs to know where to send traffic for that network. Call your ISP. They'll either setup a static route for your /24 network pointing to your switch's IP address or ask you to configure a dynamic routing protocol like RIP on your switch. Or they may just not support this.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous poster, you'll need to be sure that your ISP is staticly routing the /24 to your side of the /30.

As to your problem, verify your default gateway on that host is .1 of the /24. Do a traceroute/tracert to 4.2.2.2 or something and see how far it gets. Also, ensure its not something as simple as lacking DNS. Ensure those settings are entered as well. That 4.2.2.2 is a DNS server so you could use that if you're missing them.

Also, dont ever use RIP. Its terrible. It seems people who dont know anything about networking continue to write books about it which is why people still know what it is but you'll see in the real world that RIP is as dead to me as its stupid name might infer. Sorry to any RIP lovers out there..just stop it :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, would this also apply to internal network addresses? I have also tried creating a 192.168.2.0/24 vlan and assigned an ip within the range to the server and experience the exact same behavior, the switch and server can see each other and respond to ping but the server is unable to reach the internet. As far as dns i had already configured that on the switch and it is able to resolve just fine and the client server is configured to use the opendns servers.

Comment: @bleomycin The 192.168.2.0 network is a completely different problem. In order to get that to work, you need to enable NAT on the switch.